# Unable to use JSON.parse with results from json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, json

In my php file I have the following code

```
//create SQL to select schedule
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Schedule`";

 //create result set
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 $result_array[] = "";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
    $result_array[$row['ID']] = $row;
 }

 echo json_encode($result_array);
```

In my HTML file I have the following code

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
    var schedArray = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.ResponseText);

    alert(schedArray[0]["ID"]);
   }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getSchedule.php?q="+year,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```

When I run my HTML code I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

I belive my data is encoded correctly because running

```
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

in my ready state check nets me an array with the correct data:

```
{"0":"","1":{"ID":"1","Team":"Louisiana-Monroe","playDate":"2011-09-03","Conference":"Sun Belt","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"3":{"ID":"3","Team":"Oklahoma","playDate":"2011-09-17","Conference":"Big 10","Rank":"1","Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"4":{"ID":"4","Team":"Clemson","playDate":"2011-09-24","Conference":"ACC","Rank":"21","Bowl":"0","Site":"A"},"5":{"ID":"5","Team":"Wake Forest","playDate":"2011-10-08","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"A"},"6":{"ID":"6","Team":"Duke","playDate":"2011-10-15","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"A"},"7":{"ID":"7","Team":"Maryland","playDate":"2011-10-22","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"8":{"ID":"8","Team":"North Carolina State","playDate":"2011-10-29","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"9":{"ID":"9","Team":"Boston College","playDate":"2011-11-03","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"A"},"10":{"ID":"10","Team":"Miami (FL)","playDate":"2011-11-12","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"11":{"ID":"11","Team":"Virginia","playDate":"2011-11-19","Conference":"ACC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"12":{"ID":"12","Team":"Florida","playDate":"2011-11-26","Conference":"SEC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"A"},"13":{"ID":"13","Team":"Notre Dame","playDate":"2011-12-29","Conference":"IND","Rank":null,"Bowl":"1","Site":"N"},"14":{"ID":"14","Team":"Murray State","playDate":"2012-09-01","Conference":"Ohio Valley","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"},"15":{"ID":"15","Team":"Savannah State","playDate":"2012-09-08","Conference":"MEAC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"}}
```

I cannot figure out why I am receiving this error. I am not using JQuery and I have included json2.js in my JavaScript. Any help somebody could provide would be great.

Comment: Your abbreviation may be concealing the actual error in the JSON. Also are there really empty strings used as property names?

Comment: Can you post the JSON after the encode?

Comment: Thats no helping any , can you provide the FULL json you are trying to parse

Comment: might not help you directly but please: don't use `mysql_*` and refer to `xmlhttp` as `this` inside the `onreadystatechange` handler (`if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)`)

Comment: I've added the full JSON after the encode as represented by the `echo json_encode($result_array);` The property names are empty strings because I am running straight from the SQL query

Comment: That JSON you posted is valid, so something else must be sneaking into the response text.

Comment: So the "id" value of each row in the database is empty?  That seems pretty weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, I think, here:

```
var schedArray = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.ResponseText);
```

It should be `responseText`, lower-case "r". What's happening is that the string `"undefined"` is what the parser is actually trying to interpret, and a string starting with "u" cannot be valid JSON.

You got it right in the code that populates the debugging element to show the response.

Comment: +1, nice spotting indeed, I only looked at the last `responseText` :)

Comment: That helped! I changed it to a lower case r and I stopped getting that error. Unfortunately I now get unexpected token <. When I comment out the JSON.parse line I do not get the error.

Comment: Well there's no `<` character in the JSON you posted, so that doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: A broswer debugger like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools can help a lot here, because they make it easy to look at the response actually being received from the server.

Comment: So apparently 000webhost.com adds analytics code to the php return. That code begins with <!-- I have disabled it and everything seems to work correctly. Here's the URL I found to disable that code if anybody else is looking:
http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php?action=login

Answer (score 0):

The code that constructs the result is wrong. It should read:

```
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $result_array[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

Comment: The reason I added Num in there is because I only return one result. I believe it keeps overwriting $result_array. My output for `echo json_encode($result_array);` with that code is {"0":"","":{"ID":"15","Team":"Savannah State","playDate":"2012-09-08","Conference":"MEAC","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"}}

Comment: @evenflow58: In that case the only explanation is that the original code is misleading and `$row` does *not* have an `id` key. Are you sure it's `id` and not `ID`? What are the *exact* names of the table columns?

Comment: @Jon I think I found the problem, though I agree with you that there's something wrong with how the response object is being built.

Comment: You are correct. I change it to `$result_array[$row['id']] = $row;` and go this result:
{"0":"","1":{"ID":"1","Team":"Louisiana-Monroe","playDate":"2011-09-03","Conference":"Sun Belt","Rank":null,"Bowl":"0","Site":"H"}...
However, I'm still getting the original error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u)

Comment: @evenflow58: There are two separate errors in your code, both mine and Pointy's answers are correct.